# How to transfer uploaded file size greater than 16kb using wcf service

Tags: wpf, wcf

when I upload more than 16kb the connection was aborted in wpf application
client App.Config File

Comment: Have you considered spitting the payload into multiple messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setting a bigger maximum message size (this can be applied to both the service and client):

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="GenericBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```